# ExtJs - what install on server

Tags: extjs

I downloaded ExtJs and developed a basic application. The files created on my local area (following the guidelines) are located in the following directories:

- App/(desktop,shared)/..
- build
- generatedFiles
- node_modules
- packages
- resources

Now that I locally developed my application, what files (or directories) should go on server ?
I ran the command "npm run build" and suppose that this shoud produce something under build. So I suppose that someting from this directory should be exported.

This my current directory:

[image: my build area]

I haven't found any doc under sencha. Does anyone know if exist some docs?
Also a description of the files generated should be useful.

I need to integrate ExtJs in a web server driven with Laravel. The server side is equipped with API and enabled to handle directly a couple of pages (without extjs).

This question, for those that have difficult to understand, can be simplified with this simple: **What files or directories must be copied from my local area to the server?**

Thank you

Comment: [Here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/guides/using_systems/using_npm/building_application.html) is some documentation on how to build using `npm`.  You have to deploy the `build/production` folder to your web server.

Comment: @PeterKoltai, probably you know something that I ignore. I run the command "npm run build" and probably something happen under build directory. Then next?
On my server apache which files must be installed?
What stays under build? This entire file system?

Comment: The entire production folder, under your web root as you would do with any other website. ExtJS applications are JavaScript files with index.html, resources, css etc.

Answer (score 1):

You want to deploy everything from within your `build/production/MyApp` folder, so that the index.html is in the root.

the index.html file is what runs your application:

```
- index.html => Webpage
- main.js    => All your js files and Ext files
                the number is a timestamp, based on your build options
- resources  => Contains complied css files (typically 3 files)
- other folders seem to be custom or npm stuff. Just copy them too
```